# How to cycle through xcode windows (or open 'help' within the bottom pane)?

Tags: windows, xcode, reference, cycle

In Xcode 3.2 the help/reference pops up in a new window when I ALT, CMD, DOUBLECLICK on a class name**. In previous versions it looks like it used to open up in the bottom pane of the main Xcode window. Can I replicate that in 3.2+?

The problem I'm having is that if either one of the Xcode windows (help or main) is maximised, it's easy to loose one window behind the other, and I seem unable to cycle through the individual Xcode windows (the normal window cycling doesn't work - both windows just show up as one item, 'Xcode').

I'd be happy to find out how to cycle through the Xcode windows or bring up the help window in the bottom pane, as it was in prior versions. Currently I'm using Expose to access the hidden window - which is okay, but not optimal.

Thanks.

** ALT & DOUBLE-CLICK now brings up QuickHelp in 3.2

Comment: You're welcome xcoder; don't forget to mark my answer as the final answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Can you not simply type Command-~ (command tilde)? That works for me and is the common method of cycling between the windows of an application.

Comment: It depends on your keyboard language though. On Swedish (and some other european keyboards) it's Command-< (or command-> depending on direction you want to cycle).

Comment: Apologies Lyndsey, sorry, I misread your answer. Yes excellent, Command ~ works (the reason it didn't seem to do anything the first time is that I must have minimised the help window at some point, and it seems that Command ~ only works if neither window has been minimised). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

At least with XCode 4, but probably with 3 too, you can use `Ctrl+Command+Arrows` for navigating between tabs. The Up/Down buttons will switch between header files and source files and the Left/Right between opened windows/tabs.

Comment: Is there any way to cycle different project windows?